# how to create a table with Variables and their corresponding scale of measurement?

Tags: r

I have Load the data set “birthwt” in the R package “MASS” and attach it.

```
library(MASS)
attach(birthwt)
```

And I wnat to Prepare a table to list down the variables in the data set with their corresponding scale of measurement. Mention whether the variable is discrete or continuous where appropriate.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `scale of measurement` ?

Comment: Ronak Actually I don't know. This is my assignment

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking.
Use table() to count each factor, then divide by the number of occurrences.

```
> table(low)
    low
    0   1 
    130  59 

> table(low)/length(low)
    low
    0         1 
    0.6878307 0.3121693 

> par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> barplot(table(low))
> barplot(table(low)/length(low))
```

[image]